# How to update my collectionView using protocols?

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, uibutton

I'm working with protocols to be able to access my buttons that are set in my cell, everything is working except is not refreshing the image when I hit my button.

I try already to reload the collection view after my function and is not working, I try as well to reload individual cell but still no result. I feel that I missing something small or maybe I am doing everything wrong.

This is my function from my protocol that accesses the cell button

```
func didTapVoteUp(for cell: HomeFeedCell, vibe: PostVibe) {
    print("Tap Up Vote From HomeFeedController")

    guard let city = CityState.currentCity else { return }
    guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    let vibe = self.postVibe[indexPath.item]
    fetchUpVote(userPostId: vibe.userPostId, postId: vibe.postId, city: city)

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let values = [uid : 1]
    Database.database().reference().child("votes").child(vibe.postId).updateChildValues(values) { (err, _) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to vote for post: ", err)
            return
        }
        print("Succesfully vote for the post")
        //Here is where I tried the collectionView.reloadData
        //and collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath]) not working either
    }
}
```

I create another cell that fetches the data to be able to update the information but still not work either using the `collectionView.reloadData()`

```
func fetchUpVote(userPostId: String, postId: String, city: String) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("vibes").child("city").child(city).child(userPostId).child(postId)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        let updatePost = PostVibe(userPostId: userPostId, postId: postId, dictionary: dictionary)

        let votes = updatePost.vote
        let currentTime = updatePost.limitPostTime
        let newLimitTime = currentTime.addingTimeInterval(60.0 * 30.0).timeIntervalSince1970

        let values = ["limitPostTime" : newLimitTime, "votes" : votes + 1 ] as [String : Any]

        let updateRef = Database.database().reference().child("vibes").child("city").child(city).child(userPostId).child(postId)
        updateRef.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, reference) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to update values: ", err)
                return
            }
            print("Successfully updated it values: ", values)
            //This doesn't work either
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    })
    { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch postIdWithUserId: ", err)
    }
}

import UIKit

protocol HomePostDelegate {
func didTapVoteUp(for cell: HomeFeedCell, vibe: PostVibe)
func didTapVoteDown(for cell: HomeFeedCell, vibe: PostVibe)
}

class HomeFeedCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var vibe: PostVibe? {
    didSet {
        guard let imageUrl = vibe?.imageUrl else { return }
        placeView.loadImage(urlString: imageUrl)

        guard let profileImageUrl = vibe?.creatorImageUrl else { return }
        vibeView.userPhotoView.loadImage(urlString: profileImageUrl)
        vibeView.creatorName.text = vibe?.creatorName

        if vibe?.hasVoteUp == true && vibe?.hasVoteDown == false {
            vibeView.voteUpButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "upVoteOn"), for: .normal)
            vibeView.voteDownButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "downVoteOff"), for: .normal)

            vibeView.voteUpButton.isEnabled = false
            vibeView.voteDownButton.isEnabled = true

        } else if vibe?.hasVoteDown == true && vibe?.hasVoteUp == false{
            vibeView.voteDownButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "downVoteOn"), for: .normal)
            vibeView.voteUpButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "upVoteOff"), for: .normal)

            vibeView.voteUpButton.isEnabled = true
            vibeView.voteDownButton.isEnabled = false

        }

        guard let voteNumber = vibe?.vote else { return }
        vibeView.votesDisplay.text = "\(voteNumber)"

    }
}
}
```

What I am expecting is to update automatically the `.setImage` from my buttons that are in my `HomeFeedCell` and is not working.

The only way to update this images are if I refresh my collectionView manually or if i close the app.

Comment: can you provide code in `HomeFeedCell` when setImage?

Comment: actually you can use reloadData(), but the key is you have to save the state (to determine what image should shown), because it will be required everytime collection view is reloaded or scrolled.

Comment: @mnemonic23 I'm using didSet to change the values on the image, by saving the state means that I have to save the image? I am confused about saving the state. I'll update the code with the HomeFeedCell.

Comment: your vote has to be saved somewhere (i think you already did it by saving it to DB). i think your datasource (List of PostVibe i guess?) needs to be refreshed after successfully save it, because it still use use old hasVoteUp value. thats why its only works every app restart because you get new updated PostVibe data that you saved.